# How can I update my radiolist options on the fly in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a radiolist in a form and need to update the number of option. I load the radiolist in my controller in this way:

```
//Initialize radiolist for answers
$scope.answersList = [];
$scope.answerSelected = $scope.selectAnsweredSurvey();

for (var i=0; i<$scope.answersCount; i++) {
    $scope.answersList.push({value: $scope.answers[i].id, text:   $scope.answers[i].text});
}
```

radiolist in my html form:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <span style="100%"
    data-editable-radiolist="answerSelected"
    e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in ::answersList track by s.value"
    e-title="answer.text"
    e-ng-disabled="answeredSurvey(survey.id) || !survey.activa">
    >
  </span>
</div>
```

In addition I have a 'watch' to detect when the value of $scope.answers changes and return to make the next inside the watch:

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.answersCount; i++) {
    $scope.answersList.push({value: $scope.answers[i].id, text:   $scope.answers[i].text});
}
```

But the radiolist options do not update.
Thanks

Comment: ng-options would only work with select in combination of ng-model, what exactly you are doing there

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar This form is made with xeditable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next solve my problem.

First, I adapt my xeditable form like suggested @Sam Bartlett but

- I need to add a name attribute, If not, It can select all the options in radiolist.
- I need to use a watch wait for change in 'answers'
- And very important, in the html, the ng-model need '$parent.' before the answerSelected, If not, I can not access to this variable.

My controller:

```
//Initialize radiolist for answers
$scope.answerSelected = null;
$scope.answersList = [];

for (var i=0; i<$scope.respuestasCount; i++) {
  $scope.answersList.push({value: $scope.answers[i].id, text: $scope.answers[i].text});
}

//watch for answers
$scope.$watch('answers', function watcher(valueNew, valueOld) {
  if (valueNew !== valueOld) {
    var answersCount = $scope.answers.lenght;
    $scope.anwersList = [];
    for (var i=0; i<answersCount; i++) {
      $scope.answersList.push({value: $scope.answers[i].id, text: $scope.answers[i].text});
    }
  }
});
```

My html for radiolist:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="input" ng-repeat="answer in answersList">
    <input type="radio"
      name="answersSurvey"
      ng-model="$parent.answerSelected"
      ng-value="answer.value"
      ng-disabled="answeredSurvey(survey.id) || !survey.active"
      >
    <label>{{answer.text}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove double :: from this line. It is used for one way binding, If date get changes in controller it will not get reflected on view.  notice `e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in answersList track by s.value"`

https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solution only works for me when $scope.answers change his size, not when update a 'text'.

Comment: And Thanks for the interesting link!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your answer what you are getting from using the radiolist directive, but have you considered just using basic radio buttons?

for example:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="input" ng-repeat="answer in answersList">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="radioValue" ng-value="answer.value" ng-disabled="answeredSurvey(survey.id) || !survey.active">
    <label>{{answer.text}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would require no $watch and wouldn't rely on some directive.

**Edited to include use of ng-value over value as suggested in comments**

Comment: Use `ng-value="answer.value"` instead of `value`

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestion! The previous implementation would have worked but this is certainly a better way to write the code

Comment: I use this type of radiolist cause I'm using xeditable form. But I will try to adapt my xeditable form to a normal form to use your solution and I post a new comment. A lot of thanks.

Comment: If I use your example, I need to add the 'name' attribute to the input. If not I can select all the answers. My new code:
```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
 <div class="input" ng-repeat="answer in answersList">
  <input type="radio" name="answersSurvey" ng-model="answerSelected" ng-value="answer.value" ng-disabled="answeredSurvey(survey.id) || !survey.active">
<label>{{answer.text}}</label>
 </div>
</div>
```
Now all works but I need the watch and...
How can I obtain the the value of selected option? answerSelected allways have the same value